# Manually insert the extra thin space csquotes includes between nested quotation marks?

Tags: fontspec, csquotes

I have a peculiar problem with `csquotes`. When using `fontspec` a quote with a terminal apostrophe has no spacing between the apostrophe and the quotation mark. If I disable `fontspec` (comment out lines 3–4 in the MWE below) the problem goes away.

I am using XeLaTeX with `fontspec` and a paid for version of Baskerville in Open type format, however the problem does not appear to be related to the font, I seem to be able to reproduce it with any open type font.

The example is the Art Blakey and the Jazz Messengers song *Moanin’* and my citation guidelines say that names of songs should be included in quote marks.

The first example in the MWE shows the problem.

The second example shows that if I manually insert a thinspace using `\,` then that results in too large a space between the apostrophe and the closing quotation mark.

The third example shows that nested `\enquote` produces the correct space.

As this is not a problem that has ever arisen before, and I doubt will occur again with any regularity, the easiest solution is to manually insert the correct space as I attempted to do in the second example. But thinspace is too big. How can I manually insert the correct size space?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}
\begin{document}

  \enquote{Moanin'}           % example 1

  \enquote{Moanin'\,}         % example 2

  \enquote{\enquote{Moanin}}  % example 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\,` (thinspace) with `\kern0.5pt` or `\kern0.75pt`? (The amount of whitespace inserted by csquotes would appear to correspond to `\kern0.5pt`.)

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I hadn’t because I wasn’t aware of `\kern` before. I just tried it and that was what I was looking for. If you add that as an answer I will accept it as such.

Comment: you could also use `\enquote{Moanin\textciquote}`.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer that works too!

Comment: @ddbrierton - Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An introductory remark: If one runs your code *without* loading `Baskerville`, `\enquote{Moanin'}` automatically inserts whitespace -- in the amount of `0.5pt` -- between the apostrophe and the closing double quote. I have no idea why that's not the case as well once one runs `\setmainfont{Baskerville}`; I suppose it has to be a bug in either the Baskerville Opentype font or in the `csquotes` package.

The macro `\,` ("thinspace") inserts 1.667pt of unbreakable whitespace. To get a smaller amount of unbreakable whitespace, you could use the `\kern` command. Observe that the argument of `\kern` should not be delimited by curly braces. Speaking for myself, I think that 0.5pt of whitespace isn't quite enough to separate the single and double ending quotation marks; inserting 0.7pt or even 0.9pt seems more like it. (Of course, inserting `1.667pt` of whitespace -- that's what `\,` does -- is way too much.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}
\begin{document}

\obeylines % just for this example
\enquote{Moanin'}  --- no space
\enquote{Moanin'\kern0.5pt} --- 0.5pt (csquotes solution)
\enquote{Moanin'\kern0.7pt} --- 0.7pt
\enquote{Moanin'\kern0.9pt} --- 0.9pt
\enquote{Moanin'\,} --- thinspace/1.667pt
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mico and Ulrike Fischer who left excellent solutions in the comments.

Both `\enquote{Moanin\kern0.5pt}` and `\enquote{Moanin\textciquote}` are perfect solutions to the problem above.